# What does the apostrophe mean with the explanation of how PLS works?

Tags: notation, partial-least-squares

https://learnche.org/pid/latent-variable-modelling/projection-to-latent-structures/conceptual-mathematical-and-geometric-interpretation-of-pls

[image]

What does the ' mean with t'? I wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: This is a matter of linear algebra, not statistics. The notation is inconsistent, but almost surely it refers to the transpose.  The transpose should then also appear in the definition of covariance.

Comment: (That's a [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)), not an apostrophe.)